# Using C# Entity Framework how I can display "Select ALL" option in my combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I am working on MVC 4.0 with Entity Framework. Please consider the following action method and help me how I can display "Select All" text in my  combobox.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadCustomer()
    {
        UserPersistence User = ((UserPersistence)Session["ULTUSER"]);
        IList Customer = DBContext.CustomerGroups.Select
            (
                e => new
                {                        
                    Id = e.customerGroupCode,
                    Name = e.customerGroupCode + "-" + e.name,
                    CTY_ISO = e.CTY_ISO
                }
                ).Where(e => e.CTY_ISO == User.CTY_ISO).ToList();
        return new JsonResult { Data = new SelectList(Customer,"Id", "Name") };
    }
```

I attached this JsonResult to my combobox that is working fine but the problem is how I can display "Select All" text in the combobox.

In my view I'm using telerik MVC combobox to show this list:

```
@(Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
 .Name("customerCode")
 .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "dropdown", style = "width:90%;" })
 .AutoFill(false)
 .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax()
 .Select("LoadCustomer", "CCSTypes").Cache(true))
 .Filterable(filtering =>
 {
      filtering.FilterMode(AutoCompleteFilterMode.Contains);
 })
 .HighlightFirstMatch(true)                                        
 )
```

Thank you.

Comment: How do you generate the combo-box in your View?

Comment: Fix my problem. WIll not tell you full problem, just small part that is totally unclrear what is meant to, but fix it. What is a "selct all" option to start with?

Comment: My apologies was not mention in detail. Can you please check my updated post. Thank you

Comment: I advise you to add "Select all" manually in combo box items. Give it index of -1. So it will be displayed on top of all options. Then check for selected index and if it is -1 then load all data without filtering.

Comment: Thank you Ravlan. But if i want to display "---ALL---" in a combobox as first element in any case so how I can achieve?